# How to create a (u,v,w) array starting from a (u,v) array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I try to do a random walk for n particles in three dimensions. To do so I created an array with random initial data with n times 3 entries. Then I created a function that adds a random number between -5 and 5 to each of these entries. The problem I'm trying to solve now is that I have to iterate this T times and add the arrays of each time frame along a new axis. But I don't know how to get this done, I tried stack, apply_over_axis, concatenate, etc. How do I get this (n,3,T) array?

This is the code that I have so far (and works as I want it to)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

rng = np.random.default_rng(12345)

n=100 #number of particles
T=300 #amount of time frames

#create (n,3) array of random initial data
init = np.array([rng.uniform(100) for i in range(n*3)])
init = init.reshape(n,3)

#one random step in each entry
def randomstep(init):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(3):
            init[i,j] = init[i,j]+ rng.uniform(-5,5)
    return init
```

For getting the values along the "time axis" I tried e.g. the following, but I only get errors.

```
def tframes(T,init):
    for i in range(T):
        init = np.stack((init,randomstep(init)))
    return init
```

I would be extremely thankful if someone could help me!:)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's a good practise to minimise your example so you can find that import of plotting libraries is not needed here. Also you can reduce your script: make creation of `init` numpyic: `init = rng.uniform(100, size=(n,3))` and `def randomstep(init):  return init + rng.uniform(-5, 5, size=(n,3))`.

Comment: From this point try to call `tframes(T, init)` but my script loops forever. How do you call it?

Comment: thanks for your answer! meanwhile i tried a completely different way, thus i avoided the problem. Instead of trying to expand the array in a new axis I took an empty array (of the desired dimensions) and filled it step by step using a for loop.